# How to manage an array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, object

For a project I write a basic RPG and I stumbled upon a problem that I cannot fix. I have no java experience whatsoever, so this is my learning ground.
For my player I want to make an inventory supposedly a two-dimensional array and an equipment array (one dimensional, 8 values). I have constructors for items in separate classes which I can call from my Main function, the question is how can I use something like getters and setters to write the generated object into these arrays?
I have no code for this for I have no idea how to do it.
Nonetheless here is an item constructor and my equipment array:

```
    public Amulet(String itemName,int itemPrice,int itemLevel,int bonusType,double bonusMagn) {
            super(itemName,itemPrice,itemLevel,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,bonusType,bonusMagn);
            this.itemName = itemName;
            this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
            this.itemLevel = itemLevel;
            this.bonusType = bonusType;
            this.bonusMagn = bonusMagn;
        }
    PlayerEquipment[] equipmentArray = new PlayerEquipment[8];

// The many booleans the canWearinSlotX values defined in the super.
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
Thanks for your comments! I am sure it looks terrible to you but I made this using very basic knowledge. I don't know about EnumSet and how does it work so I look it up. The same with builders. For me starting from learnt 2-3 parameter constructors in class it was the logical step to expand it that way.

The super for this particular item is:

```
public class ItemMaster {
protected String itemName;
protected int itemPrice;
protected int itemLevel;

protected ItemMaster(String itemName,int itemPrice,int itemLevel) {
}
```

}

```
class ArmourMaster extends ItemMaster {
//Slot 1 Head,2 Chest,3 Legs,4 Foot,5 Hands,6 LeftRing,7 RightRing,8 Amulet
    protected boolean canWear1;
    protected boolean canWear2;
    protected boolean canWear3;
    protected boolean canWear4;
    protected boolean canWear5;
    protected boolean canWear6;
    protected boolean canWear7;
    protected boolean canWear8;

protected ArmourMaster(String itemName,int itemPrice,int itemLevel,boolean canWear1,boolean canWear2,boolean canWear3,boolean canWear4,boolean canWear5,boolean canWear6,boolean canWear7,boolean canWear8) {
    super(itemName,itemPrice,itemLevel);
}
```

}

```
public class JewelryMaster extends ArmourMaster {
protected int bonusType;
protected double bonusMagn;

public JewelryMaster(String itemName,int itemPrice,int itemLevel,boolean canWear1,boolean canWear2,boolean canWear3,boolean canWear4,
        boolean canWear5,boolean canWear6,boolean canWear7,boolean canWear8,int bonusType,double bonusMagn) {
    super(itemName,itemPrice,itemLevel,canWear1,canWear2,canWear3,canWear4,canWear5,canWear6,canWear7,canWear8);
}
```

}

You see it is that I intend to wear armour as well as jewelry in a particular slot and the jewelries will only have stat bonuses the armours only defense bonus. I want to keep it simpler that way.

Comment: I am very suspicious of you passing parameters to the super ctor *and* assigning them to fields.

Comment: 8 boolean parameters is very awkward and error prone. I would recommend using an `EnumSet` instead.

Comment: could you explain why you call the super constructor? What is your superclass and why do you pass so many booleans?

Comment: `super(itemName,itemPrice,itemLevel,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,bonusType,bonusMagn);` - that looks TERRIBLE! A method/constructor should take more than 2-3 parameters. It is even worse if 5-6 of those are booleans. Can you tell without looking at the source code what the 4th false mean?

Comment: Consider the builder pattern (e.g. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2). A call could look like `Amulet amu = new AmuletBuilder("GoldAmulet").price(100).level(2).type(AmuletType.RARE).build();`

Comment: @Marteng Thanks that will greatly help!